# Unable to deploy spring-boot app in Heroku using bitbucket pipelines

Tags: heroku, spring-boot, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to use bitbucket pipelines to do deploys in heroku and I created a simple web application using spring-boot.

I'm wondering if any of you have ideas about what is need it in "bitbucket-pipelines.yml" file?  This is my first time using heroku with bitbucket pipeline and I'm very lost.

My file looks like this one:

```
image: maven:3.3.9   
clone:
  depth: full

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - mvn -B clean install -P heroku # -B batch mode makes Maven less verbose
          - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD
```

Comment: In order to make it work with my current "bitbucket-pipelines.yml", I need to add a Procfile with the following "web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following steps:

1. Follow *Step 1* mentioned in [Deploy to Heroku](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-heroku-872013667.html) in Bitbucket Pipelines' documentation.
2. Please edit your "bitbucket-pipelines.yml" file with the following content:

   ```
   image: maven:3.3.9
   clone:
     depth: full
   pipelines:
     default:
       - step:
         script:
           - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD
           - mvn clean package
           - kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:<your_app_port_number> -sTCP:LISTEN)
           - java -jar target/<your-app-name>.jar &
   ```

NOTE:

1. Replace *< your_app_port_number >* and *< your-app-name >* with appropriate values.
2. Remember to check your "bitbucket-pipelines.yml" file with the [online validator](https://bitbucket-pipelines.atlassian.io/validator).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` where spring profile is specified.

```
image: maven:3.3.9

clone:
  depth: full

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Deploy to Heroku
        deployment: test   # set to test, staging or production
        script:
          - mvn -B clean package -Dspring.profiles.active=prod # -B batch mode makes Maven less verbose
          - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD
```

I have a `Profile` with:
`web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar target/my-api-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Make sure you have configured $HEROKU_API_KEY and $HEROKU_APP_NAME on BitBucket like:
[image]